# How do I keep a FTP connection alive?

Tags: python, ftp, ftputil

I used [ftputil](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation) to download a batch of files from a FTP server. It raised the error `ftputil.error.FTPIOError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`.

As described in [Documentation – ftputil](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation),

> `keep_alive()` attempts to keep the connection to the remote server active in order to prevent timeouts from happening. This method is primarily intended to keep the underlying FTP connection of an FTPHost object alive while a file is uploaded or downloaded. **This will require either an extra thread while the upload or download is in progress or calling `keep_alive` from a `callback` function**.

I called `keep_alive` from a `callback` function with,

```
ftp_host.download(source, target, callback=ftp_host.keep_alive)
```

but it raised `ERROR __main__ keep_alive() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

How do I keep a FTP connection alive?

Comment: you may need to wrap ftp_host.keep_alive in a lambda that calls it with just one parameter

Comment: what the other comment said, when you pass a function to the callback of  `ftp_host.download`, it is called with a `chunks` argument, but the `ftp_host.keep_alive` function does not take any arguments, so one way to do this would be `callback=lambda chunks:ftp_host.keep_alive`. From the docs "The callback, if given, will be invoked for each transferred chunk of data: `callback(chunk)`"

Comment: @python_user oops,it raised `ftplib.error_temp: 421 No transfer timeout (60 seconds): closing control connection`.

Comment: sadly I am out of ideas, I have not used the library before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly an answer to your question, but it may help finding an answer for your particular problem yourself. Also, a [ticket](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/IssueTracker) on the ftputil website is better for help with debugging a problem. That said, I think it's fine to ask on StackOverflow first since you don't know in advance if the problem is a simple one or not. :-)

Since FTP is a stateful protocol, client and server can't send arbitrary commands at a given time. The allowed commands and possibly replies are determined by the state the connection is in. See also the state diagrams in [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

To work around this limitation, ftputil creates a new FTP connection behind the scenes for each remote file object [1]. With this approach, you can still send commands like `chdir` or start a download while another is still in progress. However, this means that from the perspective of the server, all these FTP connections that come from a single `FTPHost` object are independent connections, so each of these connections can have their timeout at different times, depending on the usage pattern of the respective connection.

For example, there was [ftputil ticket 141](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/ticket/141), where presumably the main connection initiated by the `FTPHost` object timed out while a connection used for downloading was still usable.

In your case, it might be helpful to find out *which* of the underlying connections is timing out (the initial connection or a connection for a remote file). You can use `ftputil.session.session_factory` to create factories that have FTP debugging enabled (see the [documentation](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#session-factories)).

Unfortunately, a timeout of 60 seconds is quite short, so there are relatively many chances for timeouts.

Especially given the possibility of timeouts in FTP connections, my advice is to write software for FTP transfers in a way so that you can restart the operation (ideally with a new `FTPHost` object for robustness) where it was interrupted by the timeout. So far I haven't been able to come up with a way to universally work around timeouts. In simple cases you *may* actually be better off using `ftplib` directly, although ftputil has robustness and latency improvements that `ftplib` doesn't have. Using `ftplib` doesn't save you from timeouts, but at least you don't have any "hidden" connections that may make debugging more difficult.

---

[1] That said, if you close a remote file in ftputil, the underlying FTP connection can be reused unless it's not timed out. The library checks for a timeout before it reuses the connection.

The picture regarding timeouts is even more complicated by ftputil caching a lot of information from the server to reduce latency. For example, if you call `FTPHost.getcwd()`, the current directory is retrieved from a cached attribute, not by sending a `PWD` command to the server and thereby resetting the timeout. Stat information from directory listings is also usually cached.

Answer (score 0):

After couple hours looking for solutions I got it running without '421 Timeout' errors calling keepalive from separate thread. However your I/O Timeout error probably was caused by connection problems.

```py
import ftputil
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

fhandle = ftputil.FTPHost('host', 'user', 'pwd')

quitThread = 0

def _thread_keep_alive():
    while quitThread == 0:
        print("KEEPALIVE!")
        fhandle.keep_alive()
        sleep(25)

thread = Thread(target = _thread_keep_alive)
thread.start()

# some downloading...

quitThread = 1

fhandle.close()
```